# Does Mark 4:10-12 register as a "riddle?" If so, what is the resolution to this riddle?

Tags: mark, literary-genre

How should we understand the message of this difficult passage? Albeit, it is not a “classic” example of a riddle and might therefore better be classified as a “puzzling” passage.

We know the Bible has riddles; a *classic* example being:

> And he said unto them, Out of the eater came forth meat, and out of
> the strong came forth sweetness. And they could not in three days
> expound the riddle (Judges 14:14, KJV).
>
> וַיֹּאמֶר לָהֶם מֵהָֽאֹכֵל יָצָא מַאֲכָל וּמֵעַז יָצָא מָתוֹק וְלֹא
> יָכְלוּ לְהַגִּיד הַחִידָה שְׁלֹשֶׁת יָמִֽים׃

Whether a puzzle, riddle, or just a difficult passage, how should we understand its message, especially:

> καὶ ἔλεγεν αὐτοῖς Ὑμῖν δέδοται γνῶναι τὸ μυστήριον τῆς βασιλείας τοῦ θεοῦ· ἐκείνοις δὲ τοῖς ἔξω ἐν παραβολαῖς τὰ πάντα γίνεται
>
> Unto you it is given to know the mystery of the kingdom of God but
> unto them that are without, all these things are done in parables (Mk
> 4:11, KJV).

**Sources**

Aland, Kurt, et. al. *The Greek New Testament*. United Bible Society, 1975.

France, R.T. *The Gospel of Mark* (NIGTC). William B. Eerdman’s Publishing Company, 2002.

Stein, Robert. *The Method and Message of Jesus’ Teachings*. The Westminster Press, 1978.

*The Holy Bible*, Authorized King James Version, Thomas Nelson, 1972.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How should we understand the message of this difficult passage?"

> Mr 4:10 And when he was alone, they that were about him with the twelve asked of him the parable.
> Mr 4:11 And he said unto them, Unto you it is given to know the mystery of the kingdom of God: but unto them that are without, all [these] things are done in parables:
> Mr 4:12 That seeing they may see, and not perceive; and hearing they may hear, and not understand; lest at any time they should be converted, and [their] sins should be forgiven them.

The Psalmist suggests that the Messiah would speak riddles in parables:

> Ps 78:2 I will open my mouth in a parable: I will utter dark sayings [riddles] of old:

If one is unaware of the riddle within the parable, the presumption is made that the psalmist is being poetically redundant. Just as Samson's riddle was answered with a riddle, his answer to the disciples is also a riddle which hides the mystery until after the cross.

Questions:

1. Is the intent of the parable to hide the truth from those who are not inclined to dedicate themselves to a form of Gnosticism?
2. Is the saying a judgement on the people who don't understand?
3. Why doesn't he want them to be saved now?
4. Is it still a hidden mystery or is it now available to all?
5. What is the content of the Mystery?

Answers:

1. Is the intent of the parable to hide the truth from those who are not inclined to dedicate themselves to a form of Gnosticism?

God says that we may know him before we trust or believe in him. (Is 43:10) But knowledge does not save. (1Co 8:1) The secret teaching given to the disciples was safe because they didn't understand it either, and they forgot it. The secret teaching was about the cross. He repeatedly told them he must die, but when the time came, they did not believe it. He reminded those on the road to Emaus what he had been teaching all along. He then sent the Holy Spirit to remind them of what they had been taught but forgot.

2. Is the saying a judgement on the people who don't understand?

Yes. It is a judgement on their rebellion, not on their lack of understanding. Eze 12:2 Son of man, thou dwellest in the midst of a rebellious house, which have eyes to see, and see not; they have ears to hear, and hear not: for they [are] a rebellious house.

3. Why doesn't he want them to be saved now?

At the time, the events of the cross had not transpired. If they could be saved by teaching alone, then the cross was not required. The temptation of Christ was that he did not want to die. Even at the end he asked for the cup to be removed. Consider the temptation in the desert, to make stones into bread. The devil read the scripture literally:

> Ps 78:20 Behold, he smote the rock, that the waters gushed out, and the streams overflowed; can he give bread also? can he provide flesh for his people?

Jesus rebuffs the temptation by understanding it's riddle. He is the Rock and he will be made to be the bread when he faces the cross. Man does not live by literal bread alone, but by obedience to every word; including facing the cross. And man does not live by the cross alone, but by the resurrected and living Word of God.

Jesus was teaching in parables to fortify himself to face the cross. He dare not save them by teaching alone or he would be submitting to the temptation to not face the cross. This is prophesied by recapitulation of the idea beginning with Adam not being permitted to eat of the tree of Knowledge.

4. Is it still a hidden mystery or is it now available to all?

> Col 1:26 [Even] the mystery which hath been hid from ages and from generations, but now is made manifest to his saints:

The revelation of the mystery is the wedding banquet of the Lamb. Adam obtained his bride through his sleep as a symbol of Christ obtaining his bride through his death. Jesus looked at Zacchaeus as a symbol of himself hanging on the cross. Zac was a small man, and Jesus was the least of all the seed of woman because he served us all on the cross. Zac's name means 'pure' but he was chief tax collector and Jesus though righteous was made to be sin. He went to dinner with Zac to teach, because when Jesus was resurrected he opened the eyes of his disciples to the mystery which had been hidden from the beginning. Eating is a metaphor for learning. A banquest is a lot to eat. And as part of the mystery, the Hebrew word for 'marriage' also means 'doctrine'.

The New Testament is the explosion or banquet of teaching that took place revealing the mystery of the Old Testament.

5. What is the content of the Mystery in this parable?

It speaks of the eternal Word of God (known as Jesus Christ when in human form) and how he revealed himself through time.

v.14 The Sower, inferred to be God, sowed the Word. But the Word IS Christ. Jhn 1:1

v.15 The path is the path of Eden, and as Adam and Eve heard the teaching of the Word, who walked with them in the garden, Satan tempted them to eat the fruit and the Word was snatched away.

v.16-17 Then the Word taught them as he led them from Egypt. They initially rejoiced, but when affliction came they wished to return to their slavery.

v.18-19 The the Word was made flesh, and as the ram was caught in the thicket, the Word so cared for the world that the thorns of his care nailed him to the cross. He was unfruitful in his life and died alone having been made to be sin.

v.20 The Word was then fruitful in resurrection.

Though the parable had a meaning as a parable, it had a hidden meaning; a mystery, of the cross. The disciples would not understand it until after the cross.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it is so much a riddle (as in the the Judges passage) as it is an application of Isaiah 6:9-10:

> 9 And he said, Go, and tell this people, Hear ye indeed, but
> understand not; and see ye indeed, but perceive not.
>
> 10 Make the heart of this people fat, and make their ears heavy, and
> shut their eyes; lest they see with their eyes, and hear with their
> ears, and understand with their heart, and convert, and be healed.

Jesus acknowledged that some people were not going to understand His words.  He taught in parables, which meant that for those who put in little effort--His words were in one ear and out the other--all they heard was a simple story.  But for those who put in the effort to try to understand, they learned a principle of greater meaning.

He suggested elsewhere that greater understanding was needed, was coming, and would be given through the Holy Ghost:

> But the Comforter, which is the Holy Ghost, whom the Father will
> send in my name, he shall teach you all things, and bring all things
> to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you. (John 14:26)

Speaking in parables--recognizing that understanding will come with effort--looks like a conscious use of the same practice employed by Isaiah.

Comment: I would add that Matthew 13:10-17 makes it absolutely clear that this is the correct answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Mark 4:11 Berean Study Bible

> He replied, “The **mystery** of the kingdom of God has been given to you, but to those on the outside everything is expressed in **parables**,

Does Mark 4:10-12 register as a “riddle?”

It is more than a riddle. It is a mystery, a practical mystery. Its solution changes lives.

Strong's Concordance

> mustérion: a mystery or secret doctrine
> Definition: a mystery or secret doctrine
> Usage: a mystery, secret, of which initiation is necessary; in the NT: the counsels of God, **once hidden but now revealed** in the Gospel or some fact thereof; the Christian revelation generally; particular truths or details of the Christian revelation.

What is the resolution to this riddle?

Pulpit explains it this way:

> Our Lord here explains why he spake to the mixed multitude in parables; namely, because most of them were as yet incapable of receiving the gospel: some would not believe it, others reviled it. Therefore our Lord here encourages his own disciples to search out his words spoken in parables, and humbly to inquire into their full meaning, that so they might become able ministers and efficient preachers of the gospel. Moreover, by this he shows that this efficiency cannot be obtained by our own strength, but must be humbly sought for from God.

It is not just a riddle for intellectual curiosity. When a person solves this "riddle", it will change his understanding and more importantly his behaviors, his life.

John 6:63

> The Spirit gives life; the flesh counts for nothing. The words I have spoken to you--they are full of the Spirit and life.

The resolution shows a spiritual reality.

Answer (score 0):

### Meaning of a Parable

> **[Matt 13:10-16 ESV]** Then the disciples came and said to him, “Why do you speak to them in parables?” And he answered them, “To you it has been given to know the secrets of the kingdom of heaven, but to them it has not been given. ​For to the one who has, more will be given, and he will have an abundance, but from the one who has not, even what he has will be taken away. This is why I speak to them in parables, because seeing they do not see, and hearing they do not hear, nor do they understand. Indeed, in their case the prophecy of Isaiah is fulfilled that says: “‘“You will indeed hear but never understand, and you will indeed see but never perceive.” For this people's heart has grown dull, and with their ears they can barely hear, and their eyes they have closed, lest they should see with their eyes and hear with their ears and understand with their heart and turn, and I would heal them.’ But blessed are your eyes, for they see, and your ears, for they hear.

> **[Mark 4:11-12 NLT]** He replied, "You are permitted to understand the secret of the Kingdom of God. But I use parables for everything I say to outsiders, so that the Scriptures might be fulfilled: 'When they see what I do, they will learn nothing. When they hear what I say, they will not understand. Otherwise, they will turn to me and be forgiven.' "

All the parables have been characterized as inconspicuous, metaphor (not riddle) in this passage, not just this particular parable. The reason is explained: to him who has some, more will be given, and to him who has less, even that will be taken from him. The "outsiders" (not "without") are the corrupt hypocrite religious unbelievers here, not Gentiles as one may assume. The purpose of the Messiah was to reveal all hidden secrets or mysteries of the beginning.

Jesus revealed the full details to his disciples, but the parables are meant especially for the hardened rocks. The subtle nature of the parables are directed to condemn the hypocrite unbelievers to pronounce judgment upon them. The unbelievers already don't believe the plain truths and teachings, they would receive the message with contempt or would not even stay to hear it. The subtle, politically correct speech can be easily communicated without controversy or dispute.

Thayer defines parable as:

> 2. metaphorically, a comparing, comparison of one thing with another, likeness, similitude (Plato, Isocrates, Polybius, Plutarch):  universally, Mat 24:32; Mar 13:28; an example by which a doctrine or precept is illustrated, Mar 3:23; Luk 14:7; a thing serving as a figure of something else, Heb 9:9; this meaning also very many interpreters give the word in Heb 11:19, but see 5 below; specifically, "a narrative, fictitious but agreeable to the laws and usages of human life, by which either the duties of men or the things of God, particularly the nature and history of God's kingdom, are figuratively portrayed"
> 3. an act by which one exposes himself or his possessions to danger, a venture, risk

Parables were common in the Rabbinic teachings. Far from being cryptic as a riddle, the parables are the most powerful teachings describing the righteous impartial justice of God. They still elude the religious unbelievers as undisputed. The Messiah came to solve & reveal the problems, not introduce them.  *​I will open my mouth in a parable; I will utter dark sayings (LXX προβλήματα problema) from of old*.